# Regex to find sequence of words that can repeat

Tags: python, regex

I would like to identify the following pattern on a string (all words are separated by comma)
1. The string starts with RO,TA,PR
2. The string ends with TA,TO
3. After RO,TA,PR it can have multiples TA,PR

Example of valid patterns:
 - RO,TA,PR,TA,TO
 - RO,TA,PR,TA,PR,TA,TO
 - RO,TA,PR,TA,PR,TA,PR,TA,TO
 - RO,TA,PR,TA,PR,TA,PR,TA,PR,TA,TO
 - RO,TA,PR,TA,PR,TA,PR,TA,PR,TA,TO

Example of invalid patterns:
 - RO,PR,TA,TO
 - RO,TA,TO,PR,TA,TO
 - RO,TA,RO,TA,TO
 - RO,TA,PR,TO

Comment: Look up the Keene closure `*` operator.  Beyond that, you've already written the regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this: `^RO,TA,PR(,TA,PR)*,TA,TO$`.

To begin with **RO,TA,PR**: `^RO,TA,PR`

To end with **,TA,TO**: `,TA,TO$`

The star ***** repeat the regex inside **()** **0** or several times.